# sails endpoint y validacion de modelo

Tags: nodejs

en un proyecto con sails, tengo creado un modelo coche:

```
// Coche.js

module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    color: {
      type: 'string',
      required: false
    },

    price: {
      type: 'number,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
```

con esto, el propio sails tiene sus propios endpoints con /coche, de manera que puedo tener el get, post, delete...

Ahora, necesito crear un endpoint /coche/validate propio (solo necesito validar el post con el modelo, luego llamo a un servicio con los datos SIN ALMACENAR en BBDD). lo he definido asi:

```
(module).exports = function api(sails) {
    return {
        initialize: function(cb) {
        sails.on('router:after', function() {
            sails.router.bind('/coche/validate', validate, 'post', {});
        });

        function validate(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
/**
            como puedo "validar" mi modelo coche, si lo que tengo es req y res?
            con req.body obtengo los parametros de post, pero todos son string.
**/            return(res.json(resultado));
        }

        return cb();
        },
    }
```

el problema es que no se realmente como vinculo o trabajo con el modelo, en esta accion. Las de get, post y delete de /coche son "auto-magicas" del propio sails...

Hay alguna manera de comprobar el post (con req.body obtengo un array con los campos que llegan en el post) y validar con alguna funcion de sails esos datos con el modelo????

Answer (score 0):

Investigando un poco mas, he solucionado el problema de la siguiente manera, instalando una libreria llamada

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-req-validate

Con esta libreria instalada, ahora el objeto request tiene un nuevo metodo llamado "validate", y  podemos hacer:

```
req.validate({'price': 'number'}, false, callback);
```

donde:

- primer parametro es un array con el nombre del campo y el tipo que
  queremos validar
- false es para desactivar la validacion que viene por
  defecto (hace un response directo y a mi no me interesa)
- callback: es
  una función para decidir que hacer si la validacion es correcta o
  invalida.

si os interesa, echad un vistazo al enlace anterior, es el manual donde viene explicado mejor.